# Why is "closed" a reserved word is JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reserved-words

Well, after much head scratching this afternoon; I came to realize why my array was coming back as undefined. Despite the word 'closed' not being a reserved JS word; it seems it is some kind of reserved word elsewhere and so an array cannot be called 'closed'.

My question is this; if Javascript isn't reserving this word - what is? The browser? The OS? I read that one should avoid using it as a naming convention for variables / objects but I don't understand what else is trying to use it.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    var greatArray = [];
    var closed = [];

    alert(greatArray.length);
    alert(closed.length);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It isn't.  What problem are you having?

Comment: `closed` is not a [reserved word](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1). Please post your code.

Comment: You can definitely use [`'closed'` as a variable-name](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ud00srwp/).

Comment: vol7ron - Corrected - it was a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so much that Javascript has reserved it as that it is reserved because of where Javascript is used.  Consider this:

```
if (myWindow.closed)
```

Therefore, using `closed` as a name for a global variable must be avoided. You can use it as a local variable, though.

As mentioned by T.J. Crowder: 
It's a predefined property on window that you can't redefine, and since all properties on window are globals

Comment: Ironically, your example does allow reserved words, e.g. `window.else` is valid Javascript.

Comment: `window.closed` as a name for own variables **must be avoided**.

Comment: Yet another good reason not to use globals. There's no problem at all using `closed` **not** as a global.

Comment: That is no longer a reserved word; it is merely an object's property...

Comment: @RobertRossmann: As of ES5, yes. Prior to that, you couldn't use reserved words as literal property names.

Comment: `if (myWindow.closed)` is actually a really bad example, as it doesn't demonstrate using the global. Nor does the answer ever actually answer the question (the answer being: it's a predefined property on `window` that you can't redefine, and since all properties on `window` are globals...).

Comment: T.J Crowder - Would you be able to post that as an answer so that I can mark it as being such, or will the question get closed / deleted because it is a duplicate (rendering any answer pointless)?

Comment: As a closed question, no new answers are permitted.